# Prevent scrolling to top using .load()

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm trying to prevent the scrolling to the top when using jQuery's .load function. I've read at SO that you can use `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537777/prevent-scrolling-to-top-when-using-jquery-load) is the link to this question. But when using beginform, you don't have an event here.

I also tried to put a click event on the submit button, but this also didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

This is the code of the view. When success the function closeFancyReservationCancel is called.

```
@using (
    Ajax.BeginForm("Cancel", 
                   "Reservation", 
                   new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", 
                                     OnSuccess = "closeFancyReservationCancel"}, 
                   new { id = "cancelForm" }))
    {
        ...
    }
)
```

And this is the jQuery function

```
function closeFancyReservationCancel() {
    $.fancybox.close();
    $('#reservationList').load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/reservationList'));
}


function ResolveUrl(url) {
if (url.indexOf("~/") == 0) {
    url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
}
    return url;
}
```

Here a part of my HTML:

```
<div id="reservationList" class="tblContainer">
    @Html.Action("reservationList", "Reservation")
</div>
```

The action reservationList returns a view with the table. Only the body of the table has an `overflow: auto;`.

**EDIT: added more information**

I have a div with a list of my reservations table. I am using MVC3 to show that list. When press the cancel button, the div will reload by the .load function.

**EDIT**

Here my HTML view with the table:
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VnzLnUj3)

Comment: Write @ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/reservationList')

Comment: That won't work I guess. I am using a extern js file. This will be an incorrect notation.

Comment: is @ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/reservationList') c# method?

Comment: No, I added the method to the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537777/prevent-scrolling-to-top-when-using-jquery-load

Comment: What's with the link? In my question I said: "Here is the link to this question. But when using beginform, you don't have an event here." You can click on that link.. So I already checked that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the Scroll amount before loading. And apply the same scroll amount after load is finished

```
function closeFancyReservationCancel() {
    $.fancybox.close();
    var scroll_amount= $('#reservationList').scrollTop();
    $('#reservationList').load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/reservationList'),
                          function() {
                              $('#reservationList').scrollTop(scroll_amount);
                          });
}
```

If you want you can also use [`.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) amount.

Comment: This will scroll to the top? My question is how to prevent scrolling to the top..

Comment: This will not scroll to top. But it takes the scroll amount of the `#reservationList` and again sets it after the load is finished. For details read http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: This didn't fix my problem. Still the same issue.

Comment: Only you can debug it. you can alert the value of `scroll_amount` and check what is the problem there..

Comment: The scrollAmount is always 0 here

Comment: Use developer tool of IE to check the scroll bar is actually on div `reservationList` or the `tableDiv` or in the table inside it... You can use Firebug in Firefox also

Comment: I now put it on the right div. The amount have a value now, but it still scrolls to the top. I used this code now, but also tried with the function into the .load function.

`function closeFancyReservationCancel() {
    $.fancybox.close();
    var scroll_amount = $('#tableBodyRes').scrollTop();
    $('#reservationList').load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/reservationList'));
    alert(scroll_amount);
    $('#tableBodyRes').scrollTop(scroll_amount);   
}`

Comment: use `setTimeout` and inside timer set `$('#tableBodyRes').scrollTop(scroll_amount);` for one time after each load.

Comment: Ok that works. But only on 3 seconds (3000). And it's vissible for the eye.. I just want to do the actions and reload the div, without moving..

Comment: I also tried this code out. But it always jumps back to the top

Comment: I found the problem. Your answer is realy good. Even without the setTimeout. There was somewhere in an other function an other .load function. So it always scrolled to the top again :) Thanks!